# Valor nulo está indo para a função de erro do ajax - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo uma página de consulta de CEP onde o envio e o retorno das informações é feito em ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("PesquisarCEP", "CEP")" + "?cep" + retirarMascara($("#dsCEP").val()),
        type: "GET",
        success: function (retorno) {
            if (retorno != null) {
                $("#Logradouro").val(retorno.Logradouro);
                $("#Bairro").val(retorno.Bairro);
                $("#Estado").val(retorno.IdMunicipio.IdEstado.ID);
                ajaxBuscarMunicipio(retorno.IdMunicipio.ID, retorno.IdMunicipio.IdEstado.ID)
            }
            else {
                $.notify("Não foi encontrado o CEP: " + $("#enderecoCEP").val() + ", Você pode preencher o endereço manualmente.", { status: "danger" });
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            bootbox.alert("Oops, Não foi possivel conectar-se ao servidor da Onofre, Tente mais tarde.");
        }
```

Este AJAX chama um método quer procura o endereço informando o CEP, caso não encontra, o método retorna null.

Método da Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult PesquisarCEP(string cep)
    {
        try
        {
            CepRep repositorio = new CepRep();

            return Json(repositorio.PesquisarCEP(cep), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw new Exception("CEP não encontrado!!!!");
        }
    }
```

O problema é que, quando o método retorna null, em vez de ir para success, ele valor para o método "error" do ajax. Com o seguinte erro: "Unexpected end of JSON input".

Como fazer que o métodos "Sucess" receba o nulo normalmente?

Comment: Quando o cep não é encontrado cai sempre no catch?? Poderia tentar fazer return `Json(new{})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não retorne o valor direto, adicione a uma variável antes:

```
Json(new { endereco = repositorio.PesquisarCEP(cep)}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Depois você checa se a mesma é nula no cliente:

```
    ...
success: function (retorno) {
    if (retorno.endereco) {
    ...
    }
    else {
        $.notify("Não foi encontrado o CEP: " + $("#enderecoCEP").val() + ", Você pode preencher o endereço manualmente.", { status: "danger" });
    ...
```